# FileUpload Api using multer giving No default engine was specified and no extension was provided

Tags: node.js, multer

I am trying to create an api for user registration along with profile pic. Am using nodejs and uploading it using multer. When i trying to upload imagefile along with other attributes such as first name, last name, email, etc along with url. I am expecting the image to be able to browse from file system and store it in "uploads" folder in root directory. Also in database i am expecting to just save the url of the image and not the image file. I have also written the code but when i use postman to test it, i am getting error when sending the request. I tried creating other api without image and it worked fine so i am sure there is nothing wrong with database connection atleast. I tried sending both using from data and json at different times but it didnt worked for me.

app.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');

const userRouter = require('./users/user.router');

const app = express();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    //cb is callback . will always return error
    destination: function(req,file, cb){
        cb(null, 'uploads/')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
        //cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname)
        cb(null, `${file.fieldname}_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`);
    }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb)=>{
    //reject a file
    if(
        file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' ||
        file.mimetype === 'image/png'  || 
        file.mimetype === 'application/pdf'
    ){
        cb(null, true);
    }else{
        cb(new Error('Please select png, jpeg or pdf format'), false);
        console.log('Not correct file type');
    }
};

app.use(
    multer({
    storage:storage, 
    limits: {fileSize: 1000000000},
    fileFilter: fileFilter
    }).single('sellerimage')
);

//define the folder name for the image file to be displayed to public
//app.use('/images', express.static('uploads'));
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'uploads')));

//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded()); // x-www-form-urlencoded <form>
//app.use(bodyParser.json()); //application/json

//convert json object to javascript object
app.use(express.json()); 

app.use('/api/users', userRouter);

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    //Multer error handler
    if(err instanceof multer.MulterError){
      res.json({
          success: 0,
          message: err.message
      })
    }
    //Multer error handler ends
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  
    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
  });

app.listen(9999, () => {
    console.log("server up and running on 9999");
  });
```

user.Router.js

```
const {
  createUserWithUpload,
} = require("./user.controller");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/upload", createUserWithUpload);

module.exports = router;
```

user.controller.js

```
const {
    createUserWithUpload } = require('./user.service.js');

const { genSaltSync, hashSync } = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = {
    createUserWithUpload: (req, res) => {
        if(!req.file){
            const error = new Error("No image provided");
            error.statusCode = 422;
            throw error;
        }
        
        const body = req.body;
        body.url = req.file.path;
        const salt = genSaltSync(10);
        body.password = hashSync(body.password, salt);
        create(body, (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(500).json({
                    success: 0,
                    message: "Database connection error"
                });
            }
            return res.status(200).json({
                success: 1,
                data: results
            });
        })
    },
}
```

user.service.js

```
const pool = require("../db");

module.exports = {
  createUserWithUpload: (data, callback) => {
    pool.query(
      `INSERT INTO registration(firstName, lastName, gender, email, password, number, url) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`,
      [
        data.first_name,
        data.last_name,
        data.gender,
        data.email,
        data.password,
        data.number,
        data.url
      ],
      (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
          return callback(error);
        }
        return callback(null, results);
      }
    );
  },
};
```

Console Error:

```
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
    at new View (C:\NodeJS JWT\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:61:11)
    at Function.render (C:\NodeJS JWT\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\NodeJS JWT\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at C:\NodeJS JWT\app.js:93:9
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\NodeJS JWT\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\NodeJS JWT\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
    at C:\NodeJS JWT\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\NodeJS JWT\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\NodeJS JWT\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\NodeJS JWT\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:67:12)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have an error somewhere and express is trying to return an error page

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    //Multer error handler
    if(err instanceof multer.MulterError){
        res.json({
            success: 0,
            message: err.message
        })
    }
    //Multer error handler ends
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error'); // express trying to render view, but no view engine has been set
});
```

The error you are getting means, express is failing to render view as no default engine has been set. You can solve this in two ways

1. If your app is API only, replace `res.render()` with `res.json()` and return error message (if necessary) via JSON
2. Set default view engine with `app.set('view engine', 'pug')` -- set it to template engine you want to use

Comment: That worked for me but now getting another error as "Unexpected fields". I have posted the error image in the question

Comment: am not sure why its not logging any errors in console. Or may be i have not entered console.log() somewhere. can you help me please. Am just seeing below in console now. Can you help me please                                                                                                                  [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
server up and running on 9999